# Canvas animation synchronized with video time

Tags: javascript, animation, video, canvas, synchronization

We have to develop an application that draws some tracking representation synchronized with a video. So, with an sports example, when the *Player A* hits the ball on the video, the canvas' `Ball` representation has to appear next to *Player A* representation as if it were really hitting it.

The main problem here is we have all the tracking already done, and it comes with (tones of) position coordinates along time, for every element, like:
    
        
            70
            120
            00:00:23.335
        
        ...

My need is to be able to draw that object on *canvas* at that position (70, 120) when the video hits 00:00:23.335.

It's a lot of information, so I cannot run an `array.filter()` function on every `timeupdate`, because it would - for sure - play next frame before the filter is already done.

### The question

How can I organize that data on Javascript in a manner that I can access the position of elements on the closest actual time?

So if the video is at 00:00:23.500, I can quickly get position `x:70, y:120` because it's the closest to that moment.

### My (wrong) pov

As I already said, my only approach among this is to use an array with all that data and doing a `filter` (or a loop) to search the closest point coordinates through all the array on every video `timeupdate` event:

```
var playerA_pts = [
    {time: 23.330, x: 70, y:120},
    {time: 23.790, x: 75, y: 121},
    {time: 23.800, x: 76, y: 123},
    ...
]
```

However, that approach would have awful performance when the video is on advanced times...

### Additional information

The tracking data we are given (it's external to us) is not at constant framerate, so we can have recorded coordinates elements at different time rates between them.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi if you have video timeline in seconds then try to convert in frame based timeline.

your timeline should be as follow

```
var timeline = {
    "frame_20":{
        x:70, y : 120
    },
    "frame_21":{
        x:72, y : 135
    },
    "frame_22":{
        x:75, y : 143
    },
    "frame_23":{
        x:79, y : 150
    }
}
```

e.g. if your video is captured by 24 fps then calculate frame by following formula

var FRAME_RATE = 24;

```
   var _frameNo = Math.floor( video.currentTime / (1/FRAME_RATE) );
```

on requestAnimationFrame check video current time, convert it into frame by using given formula and get details as follow

```
    var _newPos = timeline["frame_"+ _frameNo];

    left = _newPos.x;
    top = _newPos.y;
```

Comment: It seems legit. Furthermore, I've been searching (because of my inexistent knowledge about this) on `Array` and `Object` limits on Javascript and it seems *there is no limit* (it has to do with the device performance), so I will give it a try and tell you how it has gone! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Unapedra ur welcome... let me know performance for the same.

Comment: @Unapedra if your problem is solved then mark this as a correct answer.

Comment: Yes! I'm still doing performance tests! At the moment, it works, so by today I will mark it as correct. Thank you!